# Application level transactions over non-transactional database

Tags: transactions, distributed-transactions, acid, cap

What are techniques to implement **partial transaction** support on the application level using non-transactional database?

Can You please share links to such technics?

Comment: have a look at that http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/two-phase%20commit.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique called **Last Resource Commit Optimization**. JBoss Transactions documents it some detail [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Multiple1PC) and [here](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Transactions_Development_Guide/ch11.html). It's not geared at non-transactional databases, rather, at non-XA supporting databases, but I believe the pattern may be sound enough to be applied.